# IN and OUT packets on control endpoint

Tags: usb

Can control endpoint receive IN and OUT packets
as a normal endpoint ? Or it can
only receive IN and OUT packets which follow SETUP packets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup packets are always a part of control transfers.
The host always initiates the control transfer by sending a setup packet. The IN or OUT data will follow it. Usually the USB API for control transfers includes the setup packet and the data buffer. For instance, the libusb function looks as follows:

```
int libusb_control_transfer (libusb_device_handle * dev_handle,
    uint8_t     bmRequestType,
    uint8_t     bRequest,
    uint16_t    wValue,
    uint16_t    wIndex,
    unsigned char *data,
    uint16_t    wLength,
    unsigned int    timeout 
)
```

bmRequestType, bRequest, wValue, wIndex and wLength parameters are for the setup packet.

The following document by Microsoft should also help understanding how the control transfers work:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/usb-control-transfer

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20446041)

Comment: Interesting fact: from description of `RXSTPI` bit in atmega32u4 datasheet: "This bit is inactive (cleared) if the endpoint is an IN endpoint." From this we can conclude that SETUP packets may be received by CONTROL and OUT endpoints, never IN endpoints.

Comment: @Striezel thanks for your comment, I have edited my answer.

Comment: The question is whether there may be "non-control" transfers on CONTROL endpoints.